# How can I send My Geolocation to text filed by clicking the button?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I' m designing a geo-app.
I want to do such thing, as sending my locations to the text field by clicking on the button.

For now I wrote such function:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    print (locations)
    let UserLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(UserLocation) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            let p = placemarks?.first

            print p


        }

    }


}
```

The method `CLGeocoder` helps me to get an address from **location**.
Now I want by clicking on my button send this address to my textfield

Should I write the same code into

```
@IBAction func MyLocationBtn(sender: AnyObject) {


}
```

Or how I can some use my function to get to that data? if yes, can You please help me how can i call this function and get to p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two time-consuming operations:

1. Getting user location
2. Getting an address from location.

I don't think your approach is correct, because every time when user's location change, you ask `CLCGeocoder` for informations.

I assume that you are keeping reference to LocationManager in your ViewController.
In my opinion you can try:

```
@IBAction func MyLocationBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
     let userLocation = locationManager.location // returns last user location
     if userLocation == nil {
           return 
     }

     CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
           print(error)
        } else {
           let p = placemarks?.first

           self.yourTextField.text = ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary(p.addressDictionary, true)

        }

    }
}
```

You can also disable your `MyLocationBtn` before you get user location.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      YOUR_BUTTON.enabled = false
 }
```

and enable it when you get user location:

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

      print (locations)
      let UserLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]
      if UserLocation != nil {
            YOUR_BUTTON.enabled = true
      }
 }
```

See [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary) for `ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary`.

**EDIT:**

If you want not to confuse user (when internet connection speed is low) try to display activity indicator when user taps on your button and hide it when you get placemarks.